# Batch - check if variable matches any item in a list

Tags: batch-file, match

I've got a simple script that grabs a PC's manufacturer and sets a variable:

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=2 delims==" %%A IN (`wmic csproduct get vendor /value`) DO SET VENDOR=%%A
```

What I need to do next is to check if my new `VENDOR` variable matches anything in a list:

```
Acer
Gateway 
Packard 
Alienware
ASUS
Dell Inc.
Fujitsu
HP
Compaq
Lenovo
IBM
Samsung
Sony
Toshiba
```

and then `DO COMMAND1` if found, and `DOCOMMANDB` if not found.

I think that piping the variable into `findstr` might work, but I only know `findstr` usage when you're feeding it a text file. I'm really bad at regex so I would need some guidance on that if it's the best option.

How can I accomplish the above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Slightly different approach.  You could also put all the vendors in a list and read the list with a FOR /F.

```
@echo off
for /f "usebackq tokens=2 delims==" %%A IN (`wmic csproduct get vendor /value`) DO SET VENDOR=%%A

FOR %%G IN ("Acer"
            "Gateway"
            "Packard"
            "Alienware"
            "ASUS"
            "Dell Inc."
            "Fujitsu"
            "HP"
            "Compaq"
            "Lenovo"
            "IBM"
            "Samsung"
            "Sony"
            "Toshiba") DO (
            IF /I "%vendor%"=="%%~G" GOTO MATCH
)

:NOMATCH
echo Does not match
pause
GOTO :EOF

:MATCH
echo Does match
pause
GOTO :EOF
```

If you want to read the list where each entry is on its own line.

```
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%G IN ("filelist.txt") DO IF.......
```

Answer (score 4):

If you pipe the Vendor to `findstr /I /G:Vendorlist.txt` and use conditional execution `&&` for success and `||` for fail :

```
@Echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%A IN (
  'wmic csproduct get VENDOR /value'
) DO Set VENDOR=%%A
Echo:%VENDOR%|Findstr /I /G:VENDORList.txt >NUL 2>&1 &&(
  Echo found %VENDOR% in List 
)||(
  Echo %VENDOR% not found in list
)
```

Comment: +1 This is very clean. I didn't want to use a helper file but this would have done just as well as the accepted answer. Thanks